# Calling uilabel animation with string variables swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables, animation, func

I am trying to build a UILabel animation. I want to add a variable string to the function, so that i can call it together with the variable.

I try to use the code below but it gives me error message.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Text1: UILabel!

    let myText = Array("Hello World !!!".characters)
    var myCounter = 0
    var timer:NSTimer?
    func fireTimer(){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "typeLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
fireTimer()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func typeLetter(myText  :String){
        if myCounter < myText.count {
            Text1.text = Text1.text! + String(myText[myCounter])
            let randomInterval = Double((arc4random_uniform(8)+1))/20
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomInterval, target: self, selector: "typeLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        } else {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
        myCounter++
    }
```

The error message is shown below 
[image]

May I know what's the problem and how to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has various problems.

As @luk2302 pointed out, your function `typeLetter` takes a parameter of type string, but string does not have a count property. You need to use string.characters to convert it to an array of unichars. Arrays do have a count property.

As @LeoDabus pointed out, you have 2 different variables `myText`. One is (I think) and instance variable of your view controller class (type [Character]) and the other is a parameter to your `typeLetter` function (type String). The `typeLetter` function's parameter `myText` is going to hide the instance variable `myText` so you can't use it.

A bigger problem is that you've declared your `typeLetter` function as taking a parameter of type String, but you're calling it from a timer. The only parameter that a timer passes to a function is the timer itself. You can't pass arbitrary parameters to a timer function.

You could fix all of these problems if you rewrote your `typeLetter` function to take a timer as a parameter.

```
func typeLetter(timer: NSTimer)
{
    if myCounter < myText.count {
        Text1.text = Text1.text! + String(myText[myCounter])
        let randomInterval = Double((arc4random_uniform(8)+1))/20
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomInterval,
          target: self, 
          selector: "typeLetter", 
          userInfo: nil, 
          repeats: false)
    } 
    else 
    {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
    myCounter++
}
```

When you do that, the instance variable `myText` is no longer hidden by the parameter of the same name, and the instance variable `myText` is the correct type, `[unichar]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that you need to choose a different name for your method parameter. Inside the method you cannot access your array count because your text parameter has the same name.

Comment: The funny think about this downvote is that he is using my own code from another answer i have posted here at stack overflow

Comment: Someone is going rogue - all answers have a downvote

Answer (score 0):

To get the characters count, you need to use

```
myText.characters.count
```

To solve the subscript error, you can try

```
myText[myText.startIndex.advancedBy(myCounter)]
```